# Qt - Format QColor to be used in Style Sheet?

Tags: python, qt, colors, stylesheet

In my PyQt4 program, I retrieve a QColor from the User via QColorDialog.
I then need to format this QColor to be used in a Style Sheet, which I currently achieve by calling...

```
QColor.name()
```

... which returns something like '#00ff00' which would then undergo simple string manipulation to be set as a style sheet for a widget. eg:

```
QWidget.setStyleSheet( '* { background-color: '+ QColor.name() + ' }')
```

Later in the program, the background color of the widget must be fetched (using .styleSheet() and more simple string manipulation) and converted to a string which when eval()ed, would construct a QColor of the identical color.

It must be converted to a QColor, since it is later used in a QBrush. The QColor must be converted to a **one line string** because it is written to file, and imported from said file via eval().
 (The string when eval()ed **must pass the color to the QColor constructor**, since the string is only one line).

In the end, I need something similiar (though not possible in this manner) like this:

```
ColorString = str( QtGui.QColorDialog.getColor().name() )
EvalString = "QtGui.QColor(" + ColorString +")"
```

Ofcourse, this method doesn't work because the QColor constructor does not accept such a format as '#00ff00' which is the format that QColorDialog.name() gives and which a QWidget.setStyleSheet() accepts.

How can I actually achieve this?

Is there anyway to convert a string like '#00ff00' to 3 integers representing Red, Green and Blue which could then be sent to the QColor constructor?
Thanks!

Note:
I realise that such a format '#00ff00' does involve a representation of those three colours, but I don't understand what 'ff' means, and calling .red() on a QColor does not return the integer that is suggested by the '#00ff00' format.
It's probably obvious that I don't understand colors :)

Specs:
- PyQt4
- Python 2.7
- Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [QColor.setNamedColor(name)](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#setNamedColor)

Example:

```
string_with_color = '#00ff00'  # gathered somehow

color = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
color.setNamedColor(string_with_color)
```

> but I don't understand what 'ff' means

`ff` = 255 in hexadecimal system

**EDIT**

As appears from the comments, solution was to convert Python string to `QString`

```
EvalString = "QtGui.QColor(QtCore.QString(" + ColorString +"))"
```

Comment: As I said, the string_with_color must be passed to the constructor of the QColor, since the QColor is in a single - lined string to be eval()ed.  I would certainly have used this method myself otherwise. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm using PySide instead PyQt, and `QColor(name)` works fine, maybe you need to convert `str` to QString? `EvalString = "QtGui.QColor(QString(" + ColorString +"))"`

Comment: Marvelous! You sir are a wizard.